# Question involving the truth value of two logic statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Context: Previous multiple choice question from uni exam

Statement 1: There exists a real number $x$ such that for all real numbers $y$, the sum of $x$ and $y$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

Statement 2: For all real numbers $x$, there exists a real number $y$ such that the sum of $x$ and $y$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

Can someone explain to me why Statement 2 is true yet Statement 1 is false?
Aren't they basically the same?

Comment: They are definitely **not** the same.

Comment: Consider St.1 : we are asked to evalaute if there is a real number $x$ such that $(x+y \ge 1)$ for every real $y$. Can you imagine such an $x$ ? Chosse it and call it $a$; we want that $(a+y \ge 1)$ for every $y$. What about $y=-a$ ?

Comment: IMO, the gist of this exercise is exactly to show that $\exists x \forall y$ and $\forall y \exists x$ are **not** the same.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, that explains why St.1 is false. Why is St. 2 true? Is it because you can take $y$ to be greater than or equal to $1-x$?